# Ler e importar TXT oersinalizado com 2 linhas distintas

Tags: php, txt, import

O qu eu tenho é um arquivo que vem em txt estruturado assim

```
1122010150251321872800000000000000028000000000014    000014011977890000000011903
3122010150251321872800000000000000          t19778900000150847423876256713012022
112201015025132296400000000000000000000031900000027  000005071977890000000011536
3122010150251322964000000000000000          t19778900000050857132204180013012022
1122010150251322972000000000000000176000000000005    000005011977890000000008345
3122010150251322972000000000000000          t19778900000040859540335979413012022
1122010150251322981000000000000000475000000000025    000025003977890000000032920
3122010150251322981000000000000000          t19778900000160901063628808613012022
1122010150251322984000000000000000875000000000006    000006011977890000000012082
3122010150251322984000000000000000          t19778900000050906010335975113012022
112201015025132298600000000000000000000051300000027  000012071977890000000015408
3122010150251322986000000000000000          t19778900000040908571177048713012022
1122010150251322989000000000000000675000000000004    000005011977890000000011536
3122010150251322989000000000000000          t19778900000040909343384319413012022
```

explicando

```
caracteres 0 a 4 = 1122 sempre os mesmos
caracteres 4 a 7 = local = 010
caracteres 8 a 22 = roteiro
....
ja na segunda linha
caracteres 0 a 4 = 3122 sen=mpre os mesmos
caracteres 4 a 7 = local = 010
caracteres 8 a 22 = roteiro igual os de cima
caracteres 64 a 73 = matricula.
```

nao vou colocar todas a s informaçoes dos clientes entao esta cortado esse doc mas percebam que as informações vem dividido em 2 linha e os primeiros 20 caracteres sao iguais nas 2 linhas apenas se diferenciando pelo inicio 1122 e 3122
mas essa lista é enorme sao mais 200 mil clientes todos assim
tive que fazer um substr pra ler o arquivo pois nao tem nenhum separador entao os campos tem inicio e tamanho

```
    $handle = file($path.$_REQUEST['arquivo']);
     $qt = count($handle);
        for ($i=0; $i<=count($handle)-1; $i++)
        {
        $linhas['fora'] = substr($handle[$i],0,4);
    if ($linhas['fora']== '1121'){       
        $itens = array(
        trim(substr($handle[$i], '4', '3')), // campo local
        trim(substr($handle[$i], '8', '13')),//campo rota
        trim(substr($handle[$i], '32', '6')),//campoleitura efetuada
        trim(substr($handle[$i], '44', '6')),//leitura atribuida
        trim(substr($handle[$i], '43', '6')));//consumo medido
        } 
    if ($linhas['fora']== '3121')//esse le a 2 linha
        {
    array_push($itens,trim(substr($handle[$i], '64', '8')));//campo matricula 
    
        }
 echo $itens[0].",".$itens[1].",".$itens[2].",".$itens[3].",".$itens[4].",".$itens[5]."<br>";   
    }
```

mas nao chego no resultado que preciso
preciso que retorne a linha com todos os dados da 1 e 2 linha para fazer uma query assim:

```
INSERT INTO pre_importa(`i_local`,`i_grupo`,`i_leitura`,`i_consumo_m`,`i_consumo_f`,`i_matricula`)VALUES('010','5025132187280','000028','000014','000014','38762567')
```

mas como juntar as 2 linhas sem duplicalas pra que apareça

```
 010, 5025132187280 , 000028,000014,000014,38762567
```

sendo que esse ultimo campo matricula esta na 2 linha?

Comment: esta comentado no codigo, na primeira linha o substring pega o local que começa no caracter 4 e tem 3 de tamanho , e assim por diante, bem como descrito na primeira linha tem 5 campos, e na segunda linha tem 1 campo.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, veja se na edição fiquei mais claro. so preciso que apos todo processo de substr ele me forneça um modo de adicionar no BD, pode ser uma string , uma array, so que nao consigo juntar as duas informaçãos das linha 1 e 2

Comment: Fernando Kotecki, Veja esse exemplo: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Matricula#main.php fiz com base nos dados apresentados na pergunta, aqui `caracteres 0 a 4 = 1122 sempre os mesmos` não deveria ser `caracteres 0 a 3 = 1122 sempre os mesmos`, O exemplo mostra vários intervalos de caracteres que não serão extraídos, esses intervalos estão corretos? Parece estar faltando dados. Outra coisa fiz com `fopen()/fgets()` de forma que a leitura não tomasse a memória de trabalho pois como disse 200k clientes, ler de uma ver na RAM pode gerar swap ou até atrasar a execução alguns outros processos

Comment: PS: Marquei  intervalos de caracteres que não serão processados como desconhecidos e desconhecidos2 caso ocorram numa mesma linha.

Answer (score -3):

Você pode usar uma expressão RegEx para ler as informações das duas linhas. Pelo o que eu entendi, o arquivo tem muitas linhas e a cada duas linhas é a informação de um cliente, certo?

Sendo assim, a função [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) te ajuda, montar o *pattern* é chato, mas
com algum tempo você consegue.

Um exemplo de como ficaria a expressão para reconhecer os primeiros 20 caracteres das duas linhas:

```php
$string = '1122010150251321872800000000000000028000000000014    000014011977890000000011903
3122010150251321872800000000000000          t19778900000150847423876256713012022';

preg_match_all("/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{16})(.+?)\n([0-9]{4})([0-9]{16})(.+?)\n/i", $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Acho que isso lhe dará um bom start sobre como usar a expressão regular. Veja o resultado do var_dump() no navegador e você verá como as informações já estão quebradas parecido com o que você espera.

Uma boa ferramenta que me ajudou a entender como funciona as expressões regulares foi o [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

**EDITADO:**

Depois que você colocou mais dados de amostra, e explicou como seriam separados os dados, olhe essa expressão regular, acredito que ela vá resolver:

```php
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{4}([0-9]{3})([0-9]{14})([0-9]{16})([0-9]{12}).+?([0-9]{6}).+?\n.+?t[0-9]{19}([0-9]{8}).+?\n/i", $string, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $k => $v) {
    $n_matches[$k] = [
        "i_local" => $matches[1][$k],
        "i_grupo" => $matches[2][$k],
        "i_leitura" => $matches[3][$k],
        "i_consumo_m" => $matches[4][$k],
        "i_consumo_f" => $matches[5][$k],
        "i_matricula" => $matches[6][$k],
    ];
}

var_dump($n_matches);
```

Onde você vai passar os dados pela variável `$string` para o preg_match_all(), e ele vai desmembrar as duas linhas, logo em seguida vai estruturar um array com os dados que você espera.

Comment: Whatyson Neves, o autor da pergunta a editou fazendo alguns esclarecimentos. Veja se não quer editar e modificar a sua resposta.